# Remote execution on Exchange server failed

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I want to remote enable the email-address-policy for a single mailbox on a exchange server (2010).

I can do this:

```
$samaccountname = $args[0]       # gets sam from command line

$EncryptedPassword = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\password.txt"
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $EncryptedPassword
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "xyzdom\sco_admin", $SecurePassword

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://xyzexcas01/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $Credential
Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber -CommandName Set-Mailbox
Get-Mailbox -Identity $samaccountname | Set-Mailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $True

Remove-PSSession $Session
```

It works if I open a powershell as administrator on the Orchestrator server. Then it executes the command on the exchange server as it should.

But the script does not work if Orchestrator tries to execute it. I do not know what settings Orchestrator uses when executing it. But I have a similar script, which is working with Orchestrator.

```
$samaccountname = $args[0]       # gets sam from command line

$EncryptedPassword = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\password.txt"
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $EncryptedPassword
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "xyzdom\sco_admin", $SecurePassword
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://xyzexcas01/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $Credential
Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber -CommandName enable-mailbox
 
$username_param = $samaccountname
$emailalias_param = $samaccountname
 
Invoke-Command -ArgumentList $username_param,$emailalias_param –session $Session -scriptblock {
    param($username_exc, $alias_exc)
    Enable-Mailbox -Identity $username_exc -Alias $alias_exc  -DomainController 'xyzdc01.zfpdom.zfp'

}

Remove-PSSession $Session
```

This script makes a new mailbox. It is working.

Can anyone show me a solution for the first script? I am totally new in powershell so I can't figure it out. Maybe someone can change my first script to do it with this `Invoke-Command` scriptblock. I am sure, then it will work.

Thank you.

Greetings

Comment: What do you mean by orchestrator

Comment: I don't have Orchestrator, but the difference in both scripts is that the second one (which as you say is working) uses `Invoke-Command` while the first doesn't. Parhaps adding that in helps?

Comment: Of course I want to align the first script to the second one. I need help doing this. The second was not made by myself so I have not enough powershell knowledge to make the first one look like the second one :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the commands inside the `invoke-command`, and the variables accordingly. Also, add the `get-mailbox` commandlet to the session. I am not able to try it, though, so I added the `-verbose` and `-whatif` switches as a failsafe. Note that if the `samaccountname` variable is empty, the `Set-Mailbox` will run on all mailboxes. The script can be tested standalone before running it in the Orchestrator.

```
$samaccountname = $args[0]       # gets sam from command line

$EncryptedPassword = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\password.txt"
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $EncryptedPassword
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "xyzdom\sco_admin", $SecurePassword

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://xyzexcas01/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $Credential
Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber -CommandName Set-Mailbox,Get-Mailbox
Invoke-Command -ArgumentList $samaccountname –session $Session -scriptblock {
    param($username_exc)
    Get-Mailbox -Identity $username_exc| Set-Mailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $True -verbose -whatif # remove the -whatif to perform changes
}
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Comment: that looks great! I will try that!

Comment: I've tested it. It works. Thank you very much. That is excactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Another working solution I have found out:

```
 #Parameter Laden
$samaccountname = $args[0]       # $samaccountname wird übergeben

$EncryptedPassword = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\password.txt"
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $EncryptedPassword
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "xyzdom\sco_admin", $SecurePassword

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://xyzexcas01/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $Credential
Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber -CommandName Set-Mailbox,Get-Mailbox
Get-Mailbox -Identity $samaccountname | Set-Mailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $True

Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Comment: It's just a different way to execute the same script. You shoud read the man page for `invoke-command` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1) and `about_remote` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote?view=powershell-7.1)